# Operational modes and Access levels in arm cortex

Tags: c, arm, embedded, cortex-m

When the processor is in Thread mode then it is possible to move processor to NPAL.Once you move out from PAL to NPAL being in thread mode,then its not possible to come back to PAL unless you change the processor operational mode to “Handler Mode”
One way to change the access level is to use CONTROL register.
But being in NPAL mode you cannot access the control register.Also,once the access mode is changed to NPAL,we cannot access system related interrupt registers.
So,my question is how do we go back to Privilged access level?
NPAL:Non Privileged Access level
PAL:Privilged Access Level

Comment: Please post some reference to what are you referring to. Where from are you getting your information?

Comment: There are privilege levels (privileged, unprivileged) and modes (thread, handler).  Once you're running unprivileged, typically the way you switch to privileged mode is through a "software interrupt", or "trap", or "supervisor call", which changes the level to privileged and vectors to a routine (presumably a system call, not user/application code).  On Arm Cortex you would use the `svc` instruction.  This is how most operating systems and drivers that use both levels transfer control back and forth.